# Custom design layout update not showing for CMS page

Tags: magento2, layout

I've create a xml named cms_page_view_selectable_eco_test.xml at app/design/VendorName/themeName/Magento_Cms/layout/, so the full path is /app/design/VendorName/themeName/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_eco_test.xml

This is not showing in the CMS page (the URL of this page is "eco") editing backend, see picture

[image]
. Does anyone know what is the problem?

the source code of this layout is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two files for custom layout

**1 - Create layouts.xml**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

This file will registered custom layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom">
        <label translate="true">custom layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

After creating above file you can check your custom layout in admin panel.

**2 - Create custom.xml**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom.xml

This file will manage design for your layout page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Now, flush the cache and check the new custom layout in admin panel configuration setting.

[image]

Comment: seems like this anwser is layout update, but not Custom layout update, is it possbile to use the "custom layout update" in CMS page?

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-layout-dropdown-on-cms-page-after-magento-2-3-4/